# Jest Integration Testing - How to manage global context?

Tags: integration-testing, jestjs

It doesn't seem like Jest allows all the test runs to share a global context for integration testing.  It does have globalSetup and globalTeardown options, but it doesn't seem like those hooks are intended to be a shared testing context across all test runs.  You can hack something together using these hooks, passing variables through the node process, but then other issues start to arise (Different instances of Array constructors during assertions, etc...).

If I have a fairly heavy integration test setup process, is it recommended that I only have one test run, where all my integration tests would live and have access to the shared context?

Currently my integration tests are spread across multiple files (individual entry points) and import a setup process.  However that setup process is getting run once per file.  I'm assuming that alternatively I can have one entry point and then import all my integration test files within the same context.  Is that a good/recommended option?

What's the recommended way of setting up integration tests for use in Jest?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this issue using a combination of 2 solutions:

1. Jest setupTestFrameworkScriptFile: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/23.x/configuration#setuptestframeworkscriptfile-string
2. NodeJS Global objects: https://stackabuse.com/using-global-variables-in-node-js/

Using the jest one time setup I can execute my setup only once, and store the results as variables in the NodeJS global object.

Example:

```
// package.json

"jest": {
  "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "<rootDir>/globalSetupFile.js"
}
```

```
// globalSetupFile.js

global.globalUser = createGlobalUser();
```

```
// testFile.spec.js

loginAsUser(global.globalUser.email, global.globalUser.password);
```